# Why TransitionDrawable is not working with different alpha?

Tags: android

I have tried this:

```
int firstColor = 0xFFFF0000; // red
int secondColor = 0x00FFFFFF; // transparent
Drawable[] drawables = new Drawable[] { new ColorDrawable(firstColor), new ColorDrawable(secondColor) };
TransitionDrawable d = new TransitionDrawable(drawables);
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(d);
d.startTransition(300);
```

And nothing will be changed.

I have added `Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY`

However if i use this:

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable( new ColorDrawable(secondColor) );
```

It works and action bar is translucent but I want to do this with transition.

Can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CrossFade to work with transparent `Drawable`s and Colors.

```
TransitionDrawable d = new TransitionDrawable(drawables);

d.setCrossFadeEnabled(true); // Add this code just after creating TransitionDrawable

getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(d);
d.startTransition(300);
```